# Vuelidate sameAs can't read component's data

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, vue-component, vuejs3, vuelidate

I have not been able to get Vuelidate sameAs validator working. It seems that sameAs validator can't read *this.password.new* because according to my debugging, *this* is undefined inside sameAs function. Probably I am doing something wrong but I can't find out what is wrong. All other validations are working well.

```
export default {
    name: 'login',
    setup() {
        return { 
            v$: useVuelidate()
        }
    },
    data : function() {
        return {
            name : "",
            email : "",
            password : {
                new : "",
                newRepeated : ""
            }
        }
    }, 
    validations: {
        name: {
            required,
            minLength: minLength(3)
        },
        email: {
            required,
            email
        },
        password: {
            new : {
                required,
                strongPassword(password) {
                    return (
                        /[a-z]/.test(password) && //checks for a-z
                        /[0-9]/.test(password) && //checks for 0-9
                        /\W|_/.test(password) && //checks for special char
                        password.length >= 10
                    );
                }
            },
            newRepeated : {
                sameAs : sameAs(function() {return this.password.new})
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone suggested that I should use an arrow function to keep the reference to *this*. An alternative approach is to use *.bind*. Now, I got the reference to *this* working but the validator returns always false.

I have now defined the validator like this:

```
      newRepeated : {
            sameAs : sameAs(function() {return this.password.new}.bind(this))
        }
```

I was doing some debugging. The code for the sameAs validator is the following:

```
    function sameAs (equalTo) {
  return function (value) {
    return unref(value) === unref(equalTo);
  };
}
```

It looks a little weird that in the inner return statement, there is a comparison between a string and a function. Of course, it will return always false. Is this a bug or do I understand something wrong?